# If $f \in L^0 (X, L^0 (Y))$, then $f \in L^0 (Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be *complete $\sigma$-finite* measure spaces,
- $\mu(X) < \infty$,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (Y)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\}, \\
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \nu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (Y)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho_Y (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho_Y$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (Y)$. For $f_n, f \in L^0(Y)$, we have $\hat \rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions). We define $\hat \rho_X$ on $L^0(X, \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\})$ and $\hat \rho_Z$ on $L^0(Z)$ similarly. For simplicity, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\| f \|_{L^0(X)} & := \hat \rho_X (f, 0), \\
\| f \|_{L^0(Y)} &:= \hat \rho_Y (f, 0), \\
\| f \|_{L^0(Z)} &:= \hat \rho_Z (f, 0).
\end{align*}
$$

I'm trying to prove an analogue of the main result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757040/if-f-in-l0-x-lp-textloc-y-then-f-in-l0-z) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $f \in L^0 (X, L^0 (Y))$, then $f \in L^0 (Z)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

There is a sequence $(f_n) \subset S(X, L^0 (Y))$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. in $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho_Y)$. Let
$$
f_n (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\varphi_n} 1_{A_{n, k}} (x) h_{n, k},
$$
where $h_{n, k} \in L^0 (Y)$ and $A_{n, k} \in \cal A$ with $\mu(A_{n, k}) < \infty$. Let
$$
F_n: X \times Y \to E, (x, y) \mapsto f_n(x)(y).
$$

Clearly, $F_n \in L^0 (Z)$. For $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$,
$$
\|F_n(x, \cdot) - f(x) \|_{L^0 (Y)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0,
$$
which implies $(F_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^0 (Y)$. We need some auxiliary results, i.e.,

> - [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757602/if-for-a-e-x-in-x-the-sequence-f-nx-cdot-n-is-cauchy-in-l0-y-t) Let $\mu(X) + \nu(Y) < \infty$. Let $f_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Y), \hat \rho_Y)$. Then $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$.
> - [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789816/cauchy-in-measure-implies-convergent-in-measure) The metric space $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$ is complete.
> - [Lemma 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757529/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-implies-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence) Convergence in $\hat \rho_Z$ implies $\lambda$-a.e. convergence for a subsequence

1. First, we consider the case $\nu(Y) < \infty$. By **Lemma 1**, $(F_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$. By **Lemma 2**, there is $F\in L^0(Z)$ such that $F_n \to F$ in $\hat \rho_Z$. By **Lemma 3**, there is subsequence (also denoted by $(F_n)$ for simplicity) such that $F_{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} F$ $\lambda$-a.e. I showed that for $\mu$-a.e $x \in X$ we have: [(S1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753844/let-f-in-l0x-times-y-then-for-mu-a-e-x-in-x-we-have-fx-cdot?noredirect=1&lq=1) $F_n(x, \cdot) \in L^0 (Y)$ and [(S2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753759/almost-everywhere-convergence-in-product-measure-and-that-in-coordinate-ones) $F_n(x, \cdot) \to F(x, \cdot)$ $\nu$-a.e.

We have $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. This means for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $\|f_n (x) - f(x)\|_{L^0(Y)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. By **Lemma 3** again, for  $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ there is a subsequence $\varphi_x$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $f_{\varphi_x (n)} (x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(x)$ $\nu$-a.e. and thus $F_{\varphi_x (n)} (x, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}f(x)$ $\nu$-a.e. It follows that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $F(x, \cdot) = f(x)$ $\nu$-a.e. and thus $\|F(x, \cdot) - f(x)\|_{L^0 (Y)}=0$.

2. We drop the assumption $\nu (Y) < \infty$. There is a countable measurable partition $(Y_n)$ of $Y$ such that $\sup_n \nu(Y_n) < \infty$. We define
   $$
   f_n:X \to L^0  (Y_n), x \mapsto f(x) 1_{Y_n}.
   $$

Then $f_n \in L^0(X, L^0 (Y_n))$. We apply part (1) for $f_n$ and get $f_n \in L^0 (X \times Y_n)$. We have $L^0  (Y_n)$ can be considered a closed subspace of $L^0 (Y)$. So $L^0(X, L^0 (Y_n))$ can be considered a closed subspace of $L^0(X, L^0 (Y))$ w.r.t. $\hat \rho_X$. Similarly, $L^0 (X \times Y_n)$ can be considered a closed subspace of $L^0(Z)$ w.r.t $\hat \rho_{Z}$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ $\lambda$-a.e. The $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\mu$-measurable. Clearly, $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ is $\mu$-measurable. This completes the proof.

Comment: Don't you think you are asking an excessive amount of questions per day?